# SQL using IN when value stores in another ROW

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have a few numbers that i stored into row as (1,2,3) ( lets name it as "ids" in table "some" )
And i using LEFT JOIN in another query to get some row using this field as ids
But when i wrote

```
LEFT JOIN sometable AS st WHERE some2.id IN some.ids
```

i get an error.
How i can use it correct, or maybe another way to realize that
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing comma-delimited lists of integers as a string is the wrong way to store things.  You should be using a junction table.

If you are stuck with this format and don't care about performance, you can use `find_in_set()`:

```
where find_in_set(some2.id, some.ids) > 0
```

Comment: If i right, best way is a store them as separate row and keep relations in another table, but in my case this solution do all system too complicated